# VBA - Documents.Activate function does not work properly

Tags: vba, ms-word, word-2010

I'm not very used to VBA language, so I come to you for help to solve my problem.

Basically, what I want to do is, while having a MS Word 2010 document opened, open a new one, set the focus on it and do stuff with it.

The problem I'm facing is that I can effectively open the new document, but the `.activate` function to set the function on it doesn't work, as the instructions following it are still executed in the first document.

Here is my code:

```
Private Sub BOK_Click()

*...instructions...*

'Opens a new document
Application.Documents.Add

'Select the latest opened document and sets the focus on it
Application.Documents(Application.Documents.Count).Activate

* do stuff *

End Sub
```

If it may help, the full context is :
I have a main template with 6 pre-filled templates in it, and following the choice of the user (from a drop-down form) it selects the right pre-filled template and opens it in a new Word document, then closed the main template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What Documents.Add does:

- Create a window
- Render a copy of the provided (or Normal, in this case) template
- Display it in the window
- Raise the index of all open documents by 1
- Assign index 1 to the newly added document
- Bring the window to the front and give focus to it

There's (usually) no need to explicitly activate a document you just added. If you must or want to use Activate, it's best practice to reference a document by it's name, since indexes tend to drift (as described above).

```
doc1 = ActiveDocument.Name
Documents.Add
doc2 = ActiveDocument.Name
' Do something with document2
Documents(doc1).Activate
' Do something with document1
Documents(doc2).Activate
' Do something with document2 again
```